# Compiling Objc Project With Makefile

Tags: objective-c, makefile, compilation

I'm trying to make crossplatform game and created project(http://cl.ly/5QRn). I'm trying make it but get:

```
Mark-Fedurins-iMac:Evolve hitecnologys$ make
gcc -g   -c -o OSX/AppDelegate.o OSX/AppDelegate.m
gcc -g   -c -o OSX/osx.o OSX/osx.m
gcc -g   -c -o main.o main.m
In file included from OSX/osx.m:2,
                 from main.m:6:
OSX/AppDelegate.m: In function ‘main’:
OSX/AppDelegate.m:4: error: expected expression before ‘interface’
In file included from main.m:6:
OSX/osx.m:10: error: expected expression before ‘end’
main.m:8: error: ‘app’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.m:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

What I do wrong? Please answer the stupid idiot what he should do :)
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - why are you #import'ing .m files? #import is for header (.h) files. Second, this is just a syntax error, nothing to do with the fact you're using a makefile, so your subject line is badly chosen. It's spelled "@interface", not "interface". Likewise, in main.m, you're using a variable named "app" which you haven't declared.

In general, it sounds like you need to read a language tutorial - you can't just make stuff up and expect the compiler to understand it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html

Comment: 1) I read this tutor.
2) OSXApp *app = [[OSXApp alloc] init];
   [app run];
it declared.
3) I checked all files, no syntax error.
4) "#import is for header (.h) files". I don't know this! Thx, tried, with .h file but same result 
5) I think problem in my makefile or in importing

Comment: You're attempting to #import a class interface into the middle of your main() function. Yes, you have a line that reads "`OSXApp *app = ...`" in your code - but that doesn't mean "app" is declared *correctly*. As I said before, you can't just make stuff up and expect the compiler to understand it - you need to learn the language.

Comment: The main trouble is that it writes "interface" but I defined class correctly! I tried about 20 different ways to make it but I always get It! In previous project version I get only error with interface. In current ver I get more errors(and app error too) What's wrong?

Comment: No - you *didn't* define the class correctly. I told you what you're doing wrong: Your class @interface is in the middle of a function. That is incorrect in Objective-C. You **seriously** need to read the tutorial (I don't believe you did) and learn the language - making up 20 different random ways to do it, and hoping one of them happens to work, is not an effective approach.